# Error merging arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have nested arrays and want to append the content of one array into another when the keys match.  Here is my function but instead of appending it is replacing.

```
function MergeArrays($arr, $ins)
{
    if(is_array($arr))
    {
        if(is_array($ins)) 
            foreach($ins as $k=>$v)
            {
                if(isset($arr[$k])&&is_array($v)&&is_array($arr[$k]))
                {
                    $arr[$k] = MergeArrays($arr[$k], $v);
                }
                else 
                {
                    // This is the new loop :)
                    // while (isset($arr[$k]))
                        // $k++;
                    // HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO APPEND INSTEAD OF ADD
                    $arr[$k] = $v;
                }
            }
    }
    else if(!is_array($arr)&&(strlen($arr)==0||$arr==0))
    {
        $arr=$ins;
    }
    return($arr);
}
```

Any recommendations?

Thanks

Comment: Please don't post a screengrab of your code - simply paste in the code itself and format it using the code sample ("{ }") icon in the editor.

Comment: Share the code, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the entries by either adding the arrays together, or using [`array_merge`](http://www.php.net/array_merge) to merge the arrays into a new one.

Any reason you're not using [`array_merge_recursive`](http://www.php.net/array_merge_recursive) to solve this without custom code?

Comment: I tried array_merge_recursive and visually it did the work. Nevertheless, then I iterate the result and I found that in the array that had elements (arrays) appended it did not contained the CLASSNAME property and iteration was not consistent. Any thoughts on that? I would definitely prefer to use array_merge_recursive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm reading the question properly, I'm a little confused as to what you're doing, but this might help:

As far as I can tell, you want to append to the value of $arr[k] with the value of $v. Therefore you want to concat these things together.

Therefore you want to use .= instead of = on the line below your comment.